# Why Mysql 8.0.19 explain show query did not using index on "where tinyint" but "where tinyint = true" did

Tags: mysql

Just notice that for some reason database not using index even seems the result are same.

pinned is tinyint NOT NULL

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pinned;
-- '1', 'SIMPLE', 'test_table', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4', '75.00', 'Using where'
```

But

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pinned = true;
-- '1', 'SIMPLE', 'test_table', NULL, 'ref', 'IDX_6947f25e817c4dee953583703e', 'IDX_6947f25e817c4dee953583703e', '1', 'const', '2', '100.00', NULL
```

Or even

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pinned > 0 OR pinned < 0;
-- '1', 'SIMPLE', 'test_table', NULL, 'range', 'IDX_6947f25e817c4dee953583703e','IDX_6947f25e817c4dee953583703e', '1', NULL, '3', '100.00', 'Using index condition'
```

Comment: true is a synonym for 1 in this context

Answer (score 0):

You are using index on the second query, note that MySQL's explain can be a bit confusing.

You can see the index is used because of the '**ref**' part, see this (taken from https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/operations )

**ef, range:**

Performs a B-tree traversal, walks through the leaf nodes to find all matching index entries (similar to INDEX RANGE SCAN) and fetches additional columns from the primary table store if needed (TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID). See “Using Index” to check whether the table access happens or not.

Using Index only shows that no table access has been made and the values are taken only from the index (unless the index is a composite one).

Comment: yes, but why the first query not using index? is there a reason why database choose not using index on first query?

Comment: Your query is :

'SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pinned'

you aren't setting anything in the where, so you can't actually use the index. 

If you set 'SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE pinned = 1' (or 0) this will use the index.